# Retractions of a circle

Tags: algebraic-topology

**Question**. Find all retracts of a circle $S^1$.

*Attempt*. Let $A$ be any retraction of $S^1$. Then there exists a continuous surjective map $r:S^1\to A$ such that $r(a)=a$  for all $a\in A$. So $r(A)=A$ is compact and connected.

Is it true that any compact connected subset of $S^1$ is a retraction of $S^1$? Clearly, any constant map from $S^1$ to $S^1$ is a retraction.

Thanks!

Comment: You probably need to be thinking about homotopy groups

Comment: Yes. A compact connected subset $A$ of  $S^1$ is a closed arc and you can retract $S^1$ onto any such $A$. @FShrike: Ergin is not asking for a deformation retraction, just a retraction.

Comment: @RobArthan Could you give some idea for the reason? I know that $r_*:\pi_1(S^1)\to \pi_1(A)$ is a surjective group homomorphism. By the way, I think we are not allowed to use higher homotopy groups in this problem.

Comment: I think you may have my comment mixed up with @FShrike's. If you just want a retraction (i.e., if $r$ isn't required to be a homotopy equivalence), then the retraction just fixes $A$ and then traces an arc along $A$ going along $A^C$ from one of its ends to the other. If you are looking for a deformation retraction then there isn't one because $A$ is not homotopy equivalent to $S$ (by consideration of fundamental groups, since $A$ is contractible).

Comment: I got it. Thanks!

Comment: A retraction is a map. You should write "retract".

Comment: There's one exception: the empty set is not a retract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, each compact connected subset $A \subset S^1$ is a retract of $S^1$.

Let us first understand these sets. Let $p : \mathbb R \to S^1, p(t) =e^{it} = \cos t  +i \sin t$, be the standard covering map.

1. $S^1$ itself is compact and connected. Trivially it is a retract of $S^1$.
2. All one-point subsets of $S^1$ are compact and connected. Trivially they are retracts of $S^1$.
3. Each compact connected subset $A \subsetneqq S^1$ which has more than one point is a *closed arc*. This means that it has the form $A = p([a,b])$ with some closed interval $[a,b]$ of length $b - a < 2\pi$.  Note that $p$ maps *hoemomorphically* onto $A$.
   $\phantom{}$
   To see this, pick $z_0 \in S^1 \setminus A$ and write $z_0 = e^{it_0}$. The map $p_0 : (t_0,t_0+2\pi) \xrightarrow{p} S^1 \setminus \{z_0\}$ is a homeomorphism, thus $J = p_0^{-1}(A)$ is a compact connected subset of  $\mathbb R \supset (t_0,t_0+2\pi)$ with more than one point. Each such set is a closed interval $[a,b]$. Since $[a,b] \subset (t_0,t_0+2\pi)$, it has length $< 2\pi$.
   $\phantom{}$
   Let us show that $p([a,b])$ is a retract of $S^1$.
   The restriction $\bar p : [a.a+2\pi] \to S^1$ of $p$ is a quotient map which identifies the points $a$ and $a +2\pi$ to $p(a) \in S^1$. Define
   $$r : [a,a+2\pi] \to [a,b], r(t) = \begin{cases} t & t \in [a,b] \\  b - \frac{b-a}{a + 2 \pi - b}(t-b) & t \in [b,a+2\pi] \end{cases}$$
   Since $r(a) = r(a+2\pi) = a$, we get an induced $\rho : S^1 \to S^1$ such that $\bar p \circ r = \rho \circ \bar p$. This is a retraction from $S^1$ to $p([a,b])$.